# PHP Extension return structure

Tags: php, php-extension

I am working on a PHP extension and want to let PHP return a structure. But it always causes core dump. My step is:

1. `./ext_skel --extname=test`
2. `./configure --enable-test`
3. in `php_test.h`, add:

   ```
    typedef struct  mydata {
        int   m_id;
        int   m_age;
    }MYDATA;
    PHP_FUNCTION(wrap_getMydata);`
   ```
4. In test.c, add:

   ```
    #define MY_RES_NAME "my_resource";
    static int my_resource_descriptor;
    PHP_FE(wrap_getMydata, NULL)
    ...
    ZEND_MINIT_FUNCTION(test)
    {
        /* If you have INI entries, uncomment these lines
        REGISTER_INI_ENTRIES();
        */
        resid = zend_register_list_destructors_ex(NULL, NULL, MY_RES_NAME, module_number);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    PHP_FUNCTION(test_getMydata)

    {
        zval* res;
        long int a, b;
        long int result;

        if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ll", &a, &b) == FAILURE) {
            return;
        }
        MYDATA objData;
        objData.m_id = a;
        objData.m_age = b;
        ZEND_REGISTER_RESOURCE(res, &objData, resid);
        RETURN_RESOURCE(res);
    }
   ```
5. add: `var_dump(test_getMydata(3,4))`  in `test.php`
6. then `make; make install; ./php test.php`, it prints:

   ```
    Functions available in the test extension:
    confirm_wrap_compiled
    test_getMydata
    Congratulations! You have successfully modified ext/wrap/config.m4. Module wrap is now compiled into PHP.
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
   ```
7. `$ gdb ../../bin/php core.23310`

   ```
    Loaded symbols for /home/user1/php/php-5.2.17/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/test.so 
    #0  0x00000000006388ad in execute (op_array=0x2a9569bd68) at /home/user1/php/php-5.2.17/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:92
    92                      if (EX(opline)->handler(&execute_data TSRMLS_CC) > 0) {`
   ```

What causes the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: does anybody give some clue?

Comment: i think its a problem with your variable scope
try something like:
`
     MYDATA * objData;
     objData = emalloc(sizeof(objData));
     objData->m_id= a;
     objData->m_age= b;
     ZEND_REGISTER_RESOURCE(return_value, res, resid);
`

Answer (score 0):

I had to rename the extension from `test` to `hjtest` - everything else should be pretty much in line with your posted sample.

tl;dr - the problem - and `SIGSEGV` in your sample is that you are registering a resource to a local variable `objData` - which at the end of the function is not reachable anymore - you need to use `emalloc` to get a piece of dynamic memory - which holds your `MYDATA`

As from there, you have a resource - bound to some piece of dyn. memory, you need to register a dtor function - so you can release/`efree` your registered memory.

To solve the above issue - modify your resource registration like this:

```
    MYDATA * objData=emalloc(sizeof(MYDATA));
    objData->m_id = a;
    objData->m_age = b;
    ZEND_REGISTER_RESOURCE(return_value, objData, resid);
```

and add a dtor:
... MINIT

```
 resid = zend_register_list_destructors_ex(resdtor, NULL, MY_RES_NAME, module_number);
```

and

```
static void resdtor(zend_rsrc_list_entry *rsrc TSRMLS_DC)
    {
        MYDATA *res = (MYDATA*)rsrc->ptr;
        if (res) {
          efree(res);
        }
    }
```

For full sample see this GIST: https://gist.github.com/hjanuschka/3ed54e66f017a379cf25